# Loopback read environment variables in routes

Tags: loopbackjs

I am trying to access environment variables inside my routes. These variables are defined using config.json and loaded by Loopback.

I have created test route that is returning environment variables using standard process.env, but unfortunately it returns undefined.

```
 module.exports = app => {
  app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`result: ${process.env.restApiRoot}`);
  });
};
```

It looks like that content of config.json is not set into environment variables. Is there any way how I can access these variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables defined in `server/config.json` are not available as environment variables. You can get them using `app.get("property_name")`. See [lb config.json](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/config.json.html)

Comment: It is actually `app.get('property_name')`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a normal `require` on config.json file.

`const config = require('path/to/config.json')`

After that, you can access using `config.restApiRoot`.